# process_file(sys.argv[1]) IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-idle

This is the code I am working with that comes from Practical Programming:

```
 import sys

def process_file(filename):
 '''Open, read, and print a file.'''

 input_file = open(filename, "r")
 for line in input_file:
  line = line.strip()
  print line
 input_file.close()
 if __name__ == "__main__":
  process_file(sys.argv[1])
```

After import this module in IDLE and pass a text file argument through process_file(), I receive this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    process_file("data.txt")
  File "C:\Python26\read_file_2.py", line 14, in process_file
    process_file(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I get this program to work without receiving this error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it `sys.argv[0]` or `sys.argv[1]`? You've not very consistent theer. ;) It if is 1, I'd guess that there's no parameter passed.

Comment: Firstly please post the actual code that causes the error - note that you've got `sys.argv[1]` in your code, but `sys.argv[0]` in your traceback. Secondly, please make sure your indentation is correct in your posted code - this is even more important in Python, where whitespace is significant.

Comment: My bad, I had experimented with changing the code to sys.argv[0] and copied the wrong error message. edited it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got the

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  process_file(sys.argv[1])
```

block at the same indentation level as the rest of the `process_file` definition, so it's being run when you call `process_file` from another module. I suspect that might be causing your problem - unindent it so the `if` is in line with the `def`.

Comment: This removes the error when I run this program from the command line, but does nothing for the problem in IDLE(which I am not that worried about).

Comment: So what _is_ the problem in IDLE? If you've stepped that back out, you can't hit it when you call through.

Comment: IDLE still gives the list index out of range error when I pass the .txt file through process_file().

Comment: It... can't. There's no longer any list indexing going on in that function. Have you made sure IDLE has reloaded the module since you changed it?

Answer (score 0):

you should move

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_file(sys.argv[1])
```

out of the `process_file` function. When importing into IDLE make sure `process_file` is available and pass file name to it.